# Migrate from using redis container on docker to using elasticache redis

Tags: docker, redis, amazon-elasticache

I was using a redis container on docker to hold some data, now I would like to migrate the data to Elasticache.

I have attemtpted the following steps:

1. Created a dump.rdb file from the Redis container on docker
2. Uploaded the file onto S3
3. Created a Redis cluster that's on the same VPC as the S3 bucket and selected the "Restore from backups" option

When I attempt to create the cluster, it keeps failing. Can I please have an explanation on why this happens and how to overcome this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The export might fail because you did not set the correct export policy on your S3 bucket. There are some prerequisite that you want to check in this page here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups-exporting.html
is mentioned that Elasticache needs to be able to access your backup in your S3 folder, in order to do so take a look to the step 2 of the guide it is mentioned the following

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/
2. Choose the name of the Amazon S3 bucket that you want to copy the backup to. This should be the S3 bucket that you created in Step 1: Create an Amazon S3 bucket.
3. Choose the Permissions tab and under Permissions, choose Access control list (ACL) and then choose Edit.
4. Add grantee Canonical Id 540804c33a284a299d2547575ce1010f2312ef3da9b3a053c8bc45bf233e4353 with the following options:

```
Objects: List, Write
Bucket ACL: Read, Write
```

5. Choose Save.